# Android: push notifications crash my application

Tags: android, push-notification, facebook-sdk-4.0

I implemented push notifications in my android applications. It works well when the application is open and notifications are displayed on top of my device.(also it works when the application is in the background). The problem is when the application is closed. Notification does not arrive and there is a message of crash on my screen. 
this is the piece of code that crashes

```
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
    Profile userProfile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
    String user_id = userProfile.getId();
```

the problem is in `userProfile` that is null. Why is it null when the application is closed? How can I fix it?

Comment: Can you provide some code snippets? What are you using? Google Cloud Messaging, a `Service` to parse the messages?

Comment: @PauloAvelar yes I am using GCM but the problem is not there. the problem is that the Profile of the package com.facebook.Profile is null when the application is closed

Comment: Could you please add the stacktrace?

Comment: @Eran, there is nullPointerException at the third line, so userProfile must be null, all the other stacktrace does not help